# how to check whether obfuscation done properly in automated way

Tags: java, automation, proguard, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have to validate whether the obfuscation is done properly for all the jars in an automated way.
If i give the input obfuscated jar, it has to validate class names, methods and variables and give the result.
We used proguard to obfuscate the jar files.
Please let me know if anyone knows any automated tool to check it or any other way to check it.

Comment: What do you mean by "properly"?

Comment: Well, you could just use a hash to check if proguard changed the file but I guess that is not enough for your "properly" requirement ...

Comment: properly means i want to check whether all the classes(including its methods,variables) are obfuscated and not even a single class missed from this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no existing tool as far as I can tell, however you can do this really easily by loading the target jar as a JarFile and checking if any of the original names exist in the new JarFile.